# WalletUtils.loadCredentials takes a while to answer,about 2 minutes

Tags: web3j

WalletUtils.loadCredentials takes a while to answer, about 2 minutes, running on the android devices,
Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials("password","path to file");
just this method, none other codes, has anyone ever encountered this problem?thanks.

Comment: Not an answer but misery does love company.... https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/119